# Gammu - gammu - detect under windows?

Tags: windows, detect, gammu

I am pretty new to gammu, my nokia which was working fine with it has died and I am getting a Huawei K4505 3g modem to replace it.

I would like to try using gammu-detect, but am running under windows and it isnt included in the distribution files.

Is there a way of getting it/ using it under windows, or alternatively can anyone direct me to the correct config settings for my 'new' modem.

I have searched everywhere, and have found some references to installing detect under windows, but no details as to how to actually do it!

Many thanks .... David.

update ... couldnt find windows version of --detect, but config file worked fine 
 with device = com19 and connection = at19200

NOt possible to use a usb connection type directly, so need to map modem to a virtual com port first.